# How to create an instance of an object with inherited from a parent fields?

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

I have two classes: `Word` and its child `Verb`:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    original = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Verb(Word):
    group = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    past_form= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    future_form = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

First, I created an instance of `Word`:

```
new_word = Word()
```

I did some processing with this instance, and now I need to create an instance of `Verb`, based on `new_word`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
new_verb = Verb(new_word)
```

but looks like this is not the right way.

**Important remark: I cannot override `__init__` method, because `Word` inherits from django model**

Comment: Classes (usually) need to have a `__init__()` method defined for them that will be called when instances of them are created — but you haven't defined one for the `Verb` class.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as we're lacking some important information/context. I think this might even be a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you use `class Verb(Word)` construction which is used for [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) of Word class properties and methods to Verb class.

To use properties of Word instance when creating Verb you need to add constructor (**init** method) into your Verb class like this:

```
class Verb(Word):
    def __init__(self, Word):
        # use Word properties to initialize Verb class
```

Comment: But is this a good idea to override __init__ method, since my Word class inherits from Django Model class?

Comment: You can use `super().__init__()` inside your constructor to invoke parent constructor. The only problem is that you need to know which arguments should be passed into parents constructor and pass them to your classes `__init__()` and then into `super().__init__()`.